# String representation of Tree

Tags: java, strings, tree

I have a `Tree` class, defined as follows:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private T value;    
    protected List<Tree<T>> children = new ArrayList<Tree<T>>();
    /* ... */
}
```

I want to implement the `toString()` method in this class to show the `String` representation of this `Tree`, e.g.:

```
└── root
    ├── child1
    │   └── grandchild1
    └── child2
```

I implemented in this way:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    buildString(sb, "", true);
    return sb.toString();
}

private void buildString(StringBuilder sb, String prefix, boolean isTail) {
    sb.append(isTail ? "└── " : "├── ").append(value).append(System.lineSeparator());
    prefix = prefix + (isTail ? "    " : "│   ");

    for (int i = 0; i < children.size() - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(prefix);
        children.get(i).buildString(sb, prefix, false);
    }
    if (children.size() >= 1) {
        sb.append(prefix);
        children.get(children.size() - 1).buildString(sb,prefix, true);
    }
}
```

I am looking for possible improvements or suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions (by far not complete as the other answer(s) show):

- You don't need to specify the type twice:

  ```
  protected List<Tree<T>> children = new ArrayList<Tree<T>>();
  protected List<Tree<T>> children = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- Create a new parameter `maxDepth` to limit the function nesting level.
  It should be set to a default value to follow the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment): Nobody would expect his program to crash just because he triggered the string conversion somehow.
- With very big trees the nested function calls can become a problem.
  But I wouldn't worry about it for two reasons:

  - The function is not named `archiveTree`. As a user, I wouldn't expect it to handle each and every scenario of a tree.
  - The default value `maxDepth` should reasonably prevent *out of memory* scenarios as long as the user doesn't manually provide disproportional values. If he does, it's his fault and not yours anymore.
- You sometimes have inconsistent spacing, e.g.:

  ```
  buildString(sb,prefix, true);
  buildString(sb, prefix, true);
  ```
- You could specify the `capacity` argument with a guessed value to the constructor of `StringBuilder` to prevent some unnecessary capacity allocations. **However**, as long as you haven't identified this as a noticeable bottleneck of your application, I would consider it to be premature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code:

```
Tree t = new Tree("Hi");
Tree e = new Tree("Hi");
t.getChildren().add(e); 
e.getChildren().add(t);
System.out.println(t);
```

Will give you a `RuntimeException` because you built a loop.

Practice problems:

1. Naming: The class named `Tree` but actually is a `Node`.
2. This `Node` by definition of the method `toString()` should

   > ...return a string "textually represents" this Node.
3. The Single-Responsibility-Principle is a practice that its not the responsibility of the leaf to print the whole tree. You better create a `TreeView` with the responsibility to display.

I can not give you a concrete example because I do not know if you need a loop-scanner or a maximum-deepnes(as ComFreek suggested) or anything.

Comment: +1, although I wouldn't name it `TreeView` as it is commonly used to refer to GUI tree controls. Maybe `TreeStringView` is a better fit. The name [`node`](http://google.com/search?q=programming+tree+node) also seems to be more widespread than [`limb`](http://google.com/search?q=programming+tree+limb).

Comment: Well, `Node` is much better because a `limb` may only a `limb` when there is no loop, and a loop-scanner for every modification is excessive. If you understand the `TreeView` specific, a `TreeStringTransformer` fit too and you can make the class `final`.